# XPath - determine the element position

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to create an index (determine the position in the XML) for every table but the problem is that the tables are in different depth. I plan to process the XML with XSLT transformation to FO. I Any ideas how to do this?

`Sample XML`

```
<document>
    <table> ... </table>

    <section>
        <table> ... </table>

        <subsection>
            <table> ... </table>
        </subsection>
    </section>
</document>
```

Comment: What kind of index do you want? What is your desired output?

Comment: @MattH The first table in the whole XML should have 1, the second should have 2 and so on. Like page numbering - just applied on tables. I would like to print that this table is 1 of 3 or something similar.

Comment: How are you planning to process this document? If you're looking for an XLST solution, I suggest you tag your question appropriately.

Comment: @MattH I updated the question as you said.

Comment: Good question, +1. Probably you'd be interested to know that the answer you have currently accepted isn't correct. See my answer for an explanation and a correct solution.

Comment: I don't want to have nested tables but OK. I accept the better solution. Thank you.

Comment: You might not, but the next person who has that problem and finds this thread might. :)

Comment: @Tomalak I know. That's why I accepted the other one :)

Comment: @_Tom and @_Tomalak: Thank you for your understanding, guys. @Tomalak has amazing knowledge of XSLT and XPath. Very few people are aware of the fact of the non-overlapping axes and we must educate our audience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**@Tomalak's solution isn't completely correct** and will produce wrong result in the case when there are nested tables.

The reason for this is that the XPath `preceding` and `ancestor` axes are non-overlapping.

**One correct XPath expression that gives the wanted number is:**

```
count(ancestor::table | preceding::table) + 1
```

**So, use**:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <table id="tbl_{count(ancestor::table | preceding::table) + 1}">
        <!-- further processing -->
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @_Tomalak: Don't worry too-much. Sometimes such things happen.

Answer (score 4):

This will number your tables consecutively, starting from 1.

```
<xsl:template match="table">
  <table id="tbl_{count(preceding::table) + 1}">
    <!-- further processing -->
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```