# xslt determine number and position of element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've been looking for a solution to this for a while, and I'm just not finding the answer. I'm hoping someone here can help. Here's my problem:

I'm trying to count the number of elements named `referenceID` and their position within a group, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281009/xpath-determine-the-element-position), so here's my file:

```
<file>
  <group id = "1">
    <title/>
    <para>
      <referenceID ref="123"/>
    </para>
    <title>
      <note>
        <referenceID ref="001"/>
      </note>
    </title>
  </group>
  <group id = "2">
    <para>
      <note>
        <referenceID ref="222"/>
      </note>
    </para>
  </group>
</file>
```

I'm trying to add to the `ref` attribute so that it displays the group position of the `referenceID`, regardless of depth, so my output file would be as follows:

```
<file>
  <group id = "1">
    <title/>
    <para>
      <referenceID ref="123-1"/>
    </para>
    <title>
      <note>
        <referenceID ref="001-2"/>
      </note>
    </title>
  </group>
  <group id = "2">
    <para>
      <note>
        <referenceID ref="222-1"/>
      </note>
    </para>
  </group>
</file>
```

My transform below is based on the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281009/xpath-determine-the-element-position), which numbers my references based on absolute position, but now I'm stuck. Any pointers on how I can get it to restart the count in every group?

```
<xsl:template match="referenceID">
 <xsl:variable name="refNum" select="@ref"/>
 <xsl:variable name="refAdd">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::referenceID) + 1"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:attribute name="ref">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat($refNum,'-',$refAdd)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [xsl:number](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#number) instead.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<file>
    <group id = "1">
        <title/>
        <para>
            <referenceID ref="123"/>
        </para>
        <title>
            <note>
                <referenceID ref="001"/>
            </note>
        </title>
    </group>
    <group id = "2">
        <para>
            <note>
                <referenceID ref="222"/>
            </note>
        </para>
    </group>
</file>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="referenceID">
        <xsl:variable name="nbr">
            <xsl:number level="any" from="group"/>
        </xsl:variable>        
        <referenceId ref="{concat(@ref,'-',$nbr)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='ref')]|node()"/>
        </referenceId>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<file>
   <group id="1">
      <title/>
      <para>
         <referenceID ref="123-1"/>
      </para>
      <title>
         <note>
            <referenceID ref="001-2"/>
         </note>
      </title>
   </group>
   <group id="2">
      <para>
         <note>
            <referenceID ref="222-1"/>
         </note>
      </para>
   </group>
</file>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I had never heard of xsl:number before.

Comment: +1 for code <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='ref')]|node()"/>.